# Find sum of economy, region

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

DDL Statement table name is world

```
country Economy
USA         2000
CHINA       1500
INDIA       1600
DUBAI       1000
Nepal        500
Pakistan     700
```

Show a query in oracle so that from this table we retriview this output

```
output:   Region      sum(economy)
               USA              2000
               Asia              5300
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example - ddl statements instead of "I have a table like this". This looks like a very basic assignment - I want to help you but I don't want to do your homework. what did you try ? Did you get stuck ? What errors did you get ?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a table which says which country belongs to which region:

```
create table region
  (id_region   number constraint pk_reg primary key,
   name        varchar2(20)
  );

create table country
  (id_country  number constraint pk_cou primary key,
   id_region   number constraint fk_coureg references region (id_region),
   name        varchar2(20)
  );
```

Then you'd

```
select r.name as region, 
       sum(c.economy) as sum_economy
from region r join country c on c.id_region = r.id_region
group by r.name
```

---

If you insist on doing it wrong & hardcode regions, here you are:

```
select case when country = 'USA' then 'USA' 
            else 'Asia'
       end as region,
       sum(economy) as sum_economy
from your_table
group by        
       case when country = 'USA' then 'USA' 
            else 'Asia'
       end;
```

Note that this "solution" is simply *wrong* and I suggest you do it  properly, as previously described.

Comment: There is only one table having two columns no need of joins

Comment: Really? And where does region name come from? If you put it into the same table as data you posted, then that's wrong because your data model **isn't normalized**. I showed you how to properly do it.

Comment: Using alias country as region and those country named USA it is USA and other all are considered as ASIA.I will show you my query but it has many errors

Comment: Once again, you're doing it wrong. I edited the answer and posted code which does what you wanted.